# Chain extension for pallet_utility

Tags: pallet, astar

I want to use the *as_derivative* function from *pallet_utility* in my ink! smart contract, and also use psp34 from Openbush. What steps do I need to follow to create a chain extension for *pallet_utility* and use it in my smart contract?

Answer (score 1):

There are some resources on chain extension here:

- https://use.ink/macros-attributes/chain-extension
- https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/tree/main/rand-extension